# 'sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: student3--".ID.I am trying to create a table student3 and insert values of ID and name

Tags: python, database, eclipse, sqlite

I am writing a code for a program that connects to Database file12.sqllite3 and creates table 'student3' to store ID as primary key and Name. Also, I want that if the file is not created, then it should be created. 
But my code shows error-->

sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: student3.ID

What is wrong?

**Why is this error coming? Where has the UNIQUE constraint failed?**

Here is my code :

```
       --- import sqlite3;

        conn=sqlite3.connect('file12.sqlite3');
        c=conn.cursor();``

        c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student3(ID integer 
                   PRIMARY KEY, NAME text)");
        c.execute("INSERT INTO student3 VALUES(11,'Tendo Sinha')");
        c.execute("INSERT INTO student3 VALUES(12,'Harsh Gupta')");
        c.execute("INSERT INTO student3 VALUES(13,'Vishwas Kumar')");
        c.execute("INSERT INTO student3 VALUES(14,'Goel')");
        c.execute("INSERT INTO student3 VALUES(15,'Alok')");

        conn.commit();

        c.execute("SELECT * from student3");
        print(c.fetchall());
        c.execute("SELECT ID from student3")
        print(c.fetchmany(4));

        c.execute("UPDATE student3 SET Name='Bhanu' where ID=14");
        print(c.fetchall());
```

How to rectify the error -->

sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: student3.ID

Comment: A few tips : Python does not need semicolons at the end of your lines. Sqlite3 will automatically create a new database file if it cannot find one with the required name so there is no need to do extra work there. You can also specify NULL on the primary keys in order to let SQLite3 do the insertions for you

Comment: You're trying to insert a row with an id that already exists in the table. Don't do that.

Comment: Alright! @MatthieuRaynauddeFitte

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails if you run it twice : the first time it will run just fine as you are inserting with available ID values but as soon as you run it again, you try to insert on ID values that already exist, that is what causes the exception.

The primary key values are meant to be unique, there cannot be any duplicates

I would recommend inserting this way : `c.execute("INSERT INTO student3 VALUES(NULL,'Alok')");` with a **NULL** instead of a given value for the ID. This allows SQLite to insert a value on an available value. You can therefor insert as many students as you wish with same or different names without getting the exception.

However, beware of your `c.execute("UPDATE student3 SET Name='Bhanu' where ID=14");` if you use the **NULL** insert method as you will not know the ID's in advance, you may need to search on the name itself rather than the ID or get the ID as you insert and store it as a variable for later use

Note : Since SQLite3 already does the creation of the file if it doesn't exist, you do not need to do anything there

Comment: Yeah! thanks for the advice! appreciate it @Matthieu Raynaud de Fitte

Comment: no problem ^^ if you are satisfied with the answer, don't forget to validate it ^^